# /sbin/ldconfig -p について

Tags: linux

**Q1./sbin/ldconfig -p は、どういう意味ですか？**
・キャッシュされている共有ライブラリのパスを表示する？

---

**Q2.シンボリックリンクについて**
・「/sbin/ldconfig -p」を実際に打つとシンボリックリンクが表示されるのですが、共有ライブラリはシンボリックリンクで参照することになっているのでしょうか？

---

**Q3.キャッシュについて**
・共有ライブラリをキャッシュした覚えはないのですが、「/sbin/ldconfig」と打ったら、どこかのconfファイルに書いた共有ライブラリのパス設定がキャッシュされるのでしょうか？
・どういう仕組？？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linuxコマンドの使い方はまずマニュアル(`man ldconfig`)を確認しましょう。

> -C cache
>             cache を /etc/ld.so.cache の代わりに用いる。
>
> -p     現在のキャッシュに保存されているディレクトリのリストと、ライブラリの候補を表示する。

- デフォルトでは`/etc/ld.so.cache`にリストがキャッシュされていること
- `-p`オプションの働き

が確認できるはずです。

---

実行コマンドや(ユーザー環境での)共有ライブラリの場合は、環境変数`PATH`や`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`に探索パスを設定しておくことでファイル名の指定だけで見つけ出すことができます。

`ldconfig`は**システム全体**での共有ライブラリのありかをキャッシュしておく仕組みで、「ファイル名」と「実際のファイルのありか(フルパス)」とのペアを`/etc/ld.so.cache`に保存しておく仕組みです。

Comment: 「共有ライブラリに対して必要なリンクを作成」かつ「 ライブラリをキャッシュ」するといつ意味でしょうか？ ldconfig設定=必ずキャッシュしている、という認識で合っていますか？　また「キャッシュ」の意味がよく分からないのですが、ブラウザキャッシュみたいに不安定なものではない？　「-N」と「-X」を見ると、「キャッシュ」「リンク」は必ずしも連動していないようですが、意味合い的にはパスを設定していると考えて良い？